# Конфликт, ошибки версий библиотек

Tags: android, c#, unity3d, android-library

Проект не обновленный, поддерживает версию `Android 4.0 API level 14`
добавляю `SDK Appodeal 3.1.4` и наблюдаю следующие ошибки:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details. 
E:/jdk201711\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="E:\AD\sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "E:\Unity5.5.0p4\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.8.0\AndroidManifest.xml:5] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=com.google.android.gms.version] element:
  <meta-data
      @android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
--    @android:value="7571000">
  <meta-data
      @android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
++    @android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version">
]
stdout[
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:41, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin\AndroidManifest.xml:10] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:43, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin\AndroidManifest.xml:12] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:41, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-9.8.0\AndroidManifest.xml:10] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:43, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-9.8.0\AndroidManifest.xml:11] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-ads\AndroidManifest.xml:9] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-ads\AndroidManifest.xml:10] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\yandex-metrica\AndroidManifest.xml:17] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdActivity] element.
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

так же добавляю `SDK TheoremReach 2.8.18`, и наблюдаю примерно такие же ошибки:

```
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-TEST\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.0.1\AndroidManifest.xml:5] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=com.google.android.gms.version] element:

UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()


Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:3, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-TEST\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\theoremreach-3.1.4\AndroidManifest.xml:3] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='14'> but library uses minSdkVersion='15'

UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details. 
E:/jdk201711\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="E:\AD\sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "E:\Unity5.5.0p4\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-TEST\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.0.1\AndroidManifest.xml:5] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=com.google.android.gms.version] element:
  <meta-data
      @android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
--    @android:value="7571000">
  <meta-data
      @android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
++    @android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version">
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:3, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-TEST\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\theoremreach-3.1.4\AndroidManifest.xml:3] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='14'> but library uses minSdkVersion='15'
]
stdout[
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:41, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-TEST\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin\AndroidManifest.xml:10] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:43, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-TEST\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin\AndroidManifest.xml:12] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:41, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-TEST\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-9.0.1\AndroidManifest.xml:10] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:43, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-TEST\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-9.0.1\AndroidManifest.xml:11] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity] element.
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Подскажите как решить эти ошибки? если что-то нужно, манифест и тд скину

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще да, манифесты желательны. Но проблему я и без них вижу. Вам же пишет:

```
stderr[
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.8.0\AndroidManifest.xml:5] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=com.google.android.gms.version] element:
  <meta-data
      @android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
--    @android:value="7571000">
  <meta-data
      @android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
++    @android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version">
]
```

У вас мета-информация о версии gms (`com.google.android.gms.version`) дублируется в разных манифестах.

В Unity3d проекте есть как основной манифест в **Plugins\Android**, так и, порой, присутствуют отдельные манифесты в папках плагинов.

Удалите из одного из манифестов этот метатег. Лучше тот, где захардкожено конкретное число `7571000`.

Comment: Да, спасибо, у меня после этих действий появилась другая ошибка,я с такой ошибкой не сталкивался и я не могу понять, это ошибка в следствии что я заменил эти строки, или это уже отдельная следующая ошибка,не зависящая от предыдущих действий , можете взглянуть ? (ссылка на пост https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/784926/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-failed-to-re-package-resources)