# Ошибка Failed to re-package resources

Tags: android, c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Помогите определить в чем ошибка и как ее исправить. Спасибо.

Проект не обновленный, поддерживает версию `Android 4.0 API level 14` и наблюдаю следующие ошибки:

```
  CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
    E:\AD\sdk\build-tools\25.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "E:\AD\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.appodeal.ads.unity:com.facebook.android:com.google.android.gms:com.google.unity:com.appodeal.inmobi.unity:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.clearcut:com.google.android.gms.gass:com.google.android.gms.location:com.google.android.gms.tasks:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4:com.unity3d.ads:com.unity3d.ads.android:com.appodeal.yandexmetrica.unity -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-9.8.0\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-9.8.0\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-9.8.0\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.8.0\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-clearcut-9.8.0\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-gass-9.8.0\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-location-9.8.0\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-tasks-9.8.0\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-compat-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-core-ui-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-core-utils-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-fragment-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-media-compat-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-ads\res" -S "E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res"

    stderr[
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml:2: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <RelativeLayout>
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml:61: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentStart from <RelativeLayout>
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <RelativeLayout>
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml:52: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <View>
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml:44: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <View>
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml:19: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentStart from <View>
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml:10: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <View>
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.oriplay.lamphead:layout/unityads_button_audio_toggle for configuration v17.
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_button_pause.xml:8: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <View>
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_button_pause.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.oriplay.lamphead:layout/unityads_button_pause for configuration v17.
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_view_video_play.xml:92: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentStart from <include>
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_view_video_play.xml:57: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentEnd from <LinearLayout>
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_view_video_play.xml:57: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <LinearLayout>
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_view_video_play.xml:44: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <TextView>
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_view_video_play.xml:29: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_view_video_play.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.oriplay.lamphead:layout/unityads_view_video_play for configuration v17.
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\values\common_attrs.xml:13: error: Attribute "imageAspectRatioAdjust" already defined with incompatible format.
    E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-9.8.0\res\values\values.xml:34: Original attribute defined here.
    ]
    stdout[
    Configurations:
     (default)

    Files:
      drawable\unityads_background_button_pause.xml
        Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\drawable\unityads_background_button_pause.xml
      drawable\unityads_icon_play.xml
        Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\drawable\unityads_icon_play.xml
      drawable\unityads_icon_speaker_base.xml
        Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\drawable\unityads_icon_speaker_base.xml
      drawable\unityads_icon_speaker_triangle.xml
        Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\drawable\unityads_icon_speaker_triangle.xml
      drawable\unityads_icon_speaker_waves.xml
        Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\drawable\unityads_icon_speaker_waves.xml
      layout\unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml
        Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml
      layout\unityads_button_pause.xml
        Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_button_pause.xml
      layout\unityads_view_video_paused.xml
        Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_view_video_paused.xml
      layout\unityads_view_video_play.xml
        Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_view_video_play.xml
      values\strings.xml
        Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\values\strings.xml
      AndroidManifest.xml
        Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

    Resource Dirs:
      Type drawable
        drawable\unityads_background_button_pause.xml
          Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\drawable\unityads_background_button_pause.xml
        drawable\unityads_icon_play.xml
          Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\drawable\unityads_icon_play.xml
        drawable\unityads_icon_speaker_base.xml
          Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\drawable\unityads_icon_speaker_base.xml
        drawable\unityads_icon_speaker_triangle.xml
          Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\drawable\unityads_icon_speaker_triangle.xml
        drawable\unityads_icon_speaker_waves.xml
          Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\drawable\unityads_icon_speaker_waves.xml
      Type layout
        layout\unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml
          Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml
        layout\unityads_button_pause.xml
          Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_button_pause.xml
        layout\unityads_view_video_paused.xml
          Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_view_video_paused.xml
        layout\unityads_view_video_play.xml
          Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\layout\unityads_view_video_play.xml
      Type values
        values\strings.xml
          Src: () E:\A_Project\oriplaygames-lamphead-AndroidBuild-333333333333\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unityads\res\values\strings.xml
    Including resources from package: E:\AD\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar
    applyFileOverlay for drawable
    trying overlaySet Key=common_full_open_on_phone.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=cast_ic_notification_0.png
    trying overlaySet Key=cast_ic_notification_1.png
    trying overlaySet Key=cast_ic_notification_2.png
    trying overlaySet Key=cast_ic_notification_connecting.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=cast_ic_notification_on.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_full_open_on_phone.png
    baseFile 0 has flavor hdpi-v4
    baseFile 1 has flavor xhdpi-v4
    overlayFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
    overlayFile 1 has flavor tvdpi-v4
    overlayFile 2 has flavor hdpi-v4
    overlayFile 3 has flavor xhdpi-v4
    overlayFile 4 has flavor xxhdpi-v4
    nothing matches overlay file common_full_open_on_phone.png, for flavor mdpi-v4
    nothing matches overlay file common_full_open_on_phone.png, for flavor tvdpi-v4
    found a match (2) for overlay file common_full_open_on_phone.png, for flavor hdpi-v4
    found a match (3) for overlay file common_full_open_on_phone.png, for flavor xhdpi-v4
    nothing matches overlay file common_full_open_on_phone.png, for flavor xxhdpi-v4
    trying overlaySet Key=common_ic_googleplayservices.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_dark.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_dark.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_light.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_focus_light.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_normal_dark.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_normal_light.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_dark.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_light.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_disabled_dark.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_dark.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_light.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_disabled_light.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_focus_dark.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_focus_light.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_light.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_normal_dark.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_normal_light.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_pressed_dark.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_pressed_light.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_medium_off_client.png
    trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_small_off_client.png
    trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_standard_off_client.<message truncated>
```

**Что я пробовал:**

- менял версии `build-tools 23.0.1` и до `25`, не помогло.
- выставил один и тот же во всех имеющихся манифестов `minSDKVersion` и соответствующий `targetSDKVersion`, тоже не помогло.

**Содержатся такие плагины:**

- OpenIAB
- FaceBook
- Appodeal
- UnityAds
- Admob
- Google Play Services версии
  7571000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже на дублирование библиотек. Некоторые плагины тянут с собой доп. библиотеки. Очень часто support-v4. И они, как правило, разные версии имеют.

Посмотрите по проекту .jar или .aar файлы, начинающиеся на support-v4 или support-v7. Нужно удалить дубликаты.

P.S. вы, смотрю, используете Appodeal, UnityAds и т.п. Лучше используйте какой-нибудь агрегатор для рекламных сетей. Мы используем 
[ironSource](https://www.ironsrc.com/). Вам на клиенте всего один раз код написать надо будет, а рекламные сети потом в админке на сайте можно будет менять (ну и .jar адаптеров докидывать по необходимости).

Comment: да, в папке google_play_services_lib была библиотека support-v4, я ее удалил, но ошибка осталась, именно та которую я описал, спасибо за совет ironSource, рассмотрю

Comment: @GR1995 не только её. Нужно дубли любых библиотек удалить. play-services компоненты часто дублируются, например. В общем, все дубли.

Comment: @GR1995 вы, кстати, не весь лог привели. В юнити ошибка обрезается. Поищите полный лог в Editor.log файле. Там может быть полезная информация, которая обрезалась в редакторе при выводе.

Comment: я проверил по имени библиотек в поиске, которые добавлялись с плагином при импорте, одинаковых не нашлось, а в логах я ничего явного не нашел, за что можно было уцепиться  https://fex.net/get/770384918263/271877958

Comment: @GR1995 у вас там случайно нету файла play-services-xxx.jar или play-services-xxx.aar?

Comment: Проблема была в папке google-play-services_lib, удалив ее проблема исчезла, спасибо за подсказки и правильные советы